# I want image first then text view and after that sound .. android studio

Tags: java, android, arrays, image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oj3jK.png)

I want image first then text view and after that sound ... After sliding image sound automatically call at the bottom 3 buttons previous play next....I have to slide new 20 images with sound and text...

Comment: Its for me not realy clear what the question is.

Comment: 20 images with sound and text  i want silde or swipe it side